# How do I call a method in the same controller and have the calling function stop execution on a return View?

Tags: c#, controller, action, asp.net-core-2.0

I have this,

```
public ActionResult IndexByName(string lastName)
{
    //find the name
    return View("Index", myObject);
}

public ActionResult SomeOtherAction(IFormCollection collection)
{
    if (collection["somekey"] == "search")
    {
        this.IndexByName(collection["lastname"]);
    }
    //other stuff in this method that I don't want to run if it says search
}
```

How can I keep the rest of the method SomeOtherAction from continuing?  I wanted the application to return to the View("Index") in the other method.

Comment: I don't follow your question. These look like two separate endpoints that don't talk to each other at all.

Comment: SomeOtherAction calls Index, and I wanted the system to return the View Index (in IndexByName) and stop executing in SomeOtherAction.

Comment: And `return IndexByName("something");` isn't doing that?

Comment: I did not try that.  I thought the other method would do it because it has a return View, not a "regular" return.

Comment: There's no "regular" return, there is just what you have declared in your method as return type, which is `ActionResult`. `View()` just construct and returns a `ViewResult` which, of course, inherits from `ActionResult`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, the `return` keyword will exist the current method and return control to it's calling method. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return):

> The `return` statement terminates execution of the method in which it appears and returns control to the calling method. It can also return an optional value. If the method is a `void` type, the `return` statement can be omitted.

So for example, you could use this:

```
public ActionResult IndexByName(string lastName)
{
    return View("Index", myObject);
}

public ActionResult SomeOtherAction(IFormCollection collection)
{
    if (collection["somekey"] == "search")
    {
        // This will return the result of IndexByName()
        // and exist the SomeOtherAction method
        return IndexByName(collection["lastname"]); 
    }
    else
    {
        // This will return the View SomeOtherView
        // and exist the SomeOtherAction method
        return View("SomeOtherView");
    }

    // In theorty this would  return an HTTP 200
    // but it is NEVER hit. All execution paths 
    // within this method resolved before we 
    // ever got here.
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I figured it would be like a redirect and just send me to the View.  No.